# Why is int calculation slower than string conversion?

Tags: python-3.x

I've written two different crossfoot functions, one uses simple integer calculation and one string conversion.

After measuring time, the results have been as expected. String conversion is somewhat slower.

But! If one does not print the result, but only makes an assignment to a variable, the timing is the opposite. Why?

Here's the code:

```
import time


def crossfoot(num, iterated=False):
    result = 0
    while num:
        result += num % 10
        num //= 10

    if iterated:
        num = result
        result = 0
        while num:
            result += num % 10
            num //= 10

    return result


def crossfoot2(num, iterated=False):
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(num)]

    result = sum(digits)

    if iterated and result > 9:
        return crossfoot2(result, True)

    return result
```

And here's the testing I've made:

```
start = time.process_time()
res = crossfoot(20991231235959, True)
print(res)
end = time.process_time()
print("Crossfoot : {}".format(end-start))

start = time.process_time()
res = crossfoot2(20991231235959, True)
print(res)
end = time.process_time()
print("Crossfoot2: {}".format(end-start))
```

> Results with given code:
>  Crossfoot : 2.0396000000002384e-05
>   Crossfoot2: 3.288599999999933e-05

If one removes the lines with `print(res)` the first function will be way slower than the second one.

> Results with print removed:
>   Crossfoot : 5.549999999999999e-06
>   Crossfoot2: 2.6244000000001655e-05

What is the reason for that?

This is not time critical, but I'd like to understand the cause.

Comment: `crossfoot` is faster in both cases. Maybe you missed that it's `e-06` when you removed `print`? In direct comparison, that would be 0.554 vs 2.624

Comment: @TheGamer007, of course you're right - I must have been blind. Just post it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crossfoot` remains faster in both cases. You probably missed that it's `e-06` when you remove the `print` call.

With both at `e-05`, that would be 0.554 vs 2.624